# Figuring out how much method takes to load

Tags: android, android-studio

I was just wondering if there is a way for me to check how much time an activity takes to load and how much each individual method inside the activity takes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can user [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time)  to measure startup-time

For example, you can use the following adb command to measure launch time:

```
adb [-d|-e|-s <serialNumber>] shell am start -S -W com.example.app/.MainActivity
-c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
-a android.intent.action.MAIN
```

For measuring method performance, you can either add logging statements and/or use the [CPU profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler).

Comment: for some reason the profiler always  crashes my app with a "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)" error is there a way on how to fix it ?

Comment: That's a different question. But without seeing your code it is hard to tell.